# Different gradle wrapper version for Module

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a project with several sub projects and I have issue where one of the sub projects requires gradle 4.9 when the other projects with the latest.

Is there anyway to set the gradle wrapper version for this module?

I tried adding the all the gradle build files to the sub project root with the correct gradle version, but it still detects and uses parent project gradle version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you need to set up [a Composite Build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Comment: Set up each Gradle proect to be an independent Gradle build with its own settings.gradle file.